Is "tension" the correct term for the restoring force of two opposing rubber bands?
The following is from Mathematical Physics by Donald Menzel:

Consider a point-mass $P$ attached to the centers of three mutually
perpendicular stretched rubber bands and held in static equilibrium
by the force of elasticity. Take a set of Cartesian axes parallel
to the bands. The mass, if displaced a small distance parallel to
the $x$-axis, will experience a restoring force proportional to and
opposite in sign to the displacement, i.e.,
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{F}= & -\hat{\mathfrak{i}}a_{x}x,
\end{align*}
where $a_{x}$ measures the tension of the band on the $x$-axis.
We suppose the bands to be so long compared with the displacement
that the restoring force in the $x$-direction produced by the crossed
$yz$-bands is negligibly small.

If we assume the system is symmetric, then both halves of the $x$ rubber band will have a Hooke constant $k.$  Let $X_o$ be the relaxed length, and $X=X_o+2\Delta X$ the equilibrium length of the $x$ rubber band.  The equilibrium tension is $\tau=k\Delta X$. A small displacement $x$ increases the tension in the left side by $kx$ and decreases that of the right side by $kx.$  So the restoring force will be $f_x=-2kx.$ This is independent of $\Delta X,$ and, therefore independent of $\tau.$
So it seems clear to me that "tension" is not the appropriate term for $a_x.$  Am I correct about this?

(a) "$F = ia_xx" What's the "" ? (b) Tension isn't a force but a combination of equal and opposite forces acting on either end of a sample of material, tending to stretch that sample.

Sorry, that's a basis vector.  I put a hat on it in response to your comment.

The force on $P$ is what we might call the tension differential across $P$.

When I asked this question I hadn't seen any way that Menzel's $a_x$ "measures the tension of the band".  But I wanted to know if there was some interpretation I was missing.  Since I have not been given any reason to call this quantity "tension" and it is independent of the tension within the range where Hooke's law applies, I conclude that "tension" is not the correct term to use here.
The mathematical statement of the same is as follows:
Let $x$ be the displacement from equilibrium. Assume a symmetric system where the relaxed length of each band is $\mathcal l_o,$ Hooke's constant is $k,$ and $\mathcal l$ is the equilibrium length of each band.  The equilibrium tension is $T_o=k \left(\mathcal l-\mathcal l_o\right).$  The tension in one band will be $T_1=T_o+kx.$  The other tension will be $T_2=T_o-kx.$ Thus the restoring force will be $f=-2kx=-a_{x}x=T_2-T_1.$  So Menzel's term is $a_x=2k$ which is independent of the tension.

Please don't down-vote without providing a reason.  All you have accomplished by down-voting without explanation is to convince me that people who don't know physics are participating in this community.


So it seems clear to me that "tension" is not the appropriate term for $a_x$.

The key point is that the restoring force is "proportional to and opposite in sign to the displacement" and the constant of proportionality is $a_x$. Whether or not you choose to call this "tension" is immaterial.

If there were some justification for using the term "tension" in this context, I might accept it.  As it stands, it is apparently incorrect.  Tension has a specific meaning in physics.  As far as I can see, it is not applicable in this context.

@StevenThomasHatton I don't see why the restoring force should not be called a tension. Strictly speaking it is the difference between two tensions, one in each direction. I see no harm in calling this difference a tension (the difference between two forces is still a force etc.), but if you prefer to call it a tension differential that is fine too - it is only a label.

$a_x$ is not the restoring force.  It is analogous to Hooke's spring constant. It is the derivative of force with respect to displacement.
